# Does NP-hard problems have to be decision problems?

Tags: reductions, np-hard, np

According to the selected answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857244/what-are-the-differences-between-np-np-complete-and-np-hard) NP-hard problems do NOT have to be decision problem. But by definition all NP-hard problems can be karp-reduced from any NP-problem in polynomial time; thus, implying that the answer from the reduction must be the same as the NP-problem which is yes/no `=>` decision problem. So isn't NP-hard problems in fact always decision problems?

Comment: This seems to be covered by https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/11009/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/67300/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/84076/755, and the [Wikipedia article on NP-hardness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness)  ("NP-hard: Class of decision problems which are...").  In the future I encourage you to do more research to check whether the question is already answered on this site or in standard resources.

Comment: @D.W. Well in the link I gave in my question there was an answer to a question with over 1k upvotes that said explicitly "NP-hard problems do not have to be in NP, and they do not have to be decision problems."

Comment: As Yuval Filmus wrote, Stack Overflow is a site for programmers.  In any case I think your question is basically the same as https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/67300/755 ("How can the "non-decision problem" version be NP-hard? Doesn't this class contain decision problems, by definition? "), and the question is answered there ("When we say that an optimization problem is NP-hard, what we mean is that its decision version is NP-hard.").

Comment: @D.W. Yes, thanks. I got the answer I was looking for. But computer science is the theoretical background for programming so I don't understand your point there. And it doesn't explain why they would say things that would be incorrect. Well anyway, they did this time I suppose, and that's why I asked the question here, which is what I was trying to clarify.

Comment: @I wish this wouldn't have been closed. It is the most direct and Googleable version of the question.